# Is C++ a turing complete language?

Tags: c++, turing-machines

Is C++ a turing complete language?

Obviously that would be the case, but how is it proven practically?

Is there a minimally reproducible example that shows that this is the case?

Comment: In order to do so, you would need to prove, that C++ is at least as powerful as a turing machine. One way to go, would be to write a turing machine in C++, having the program emulate a turing machine.

Comment: "nearly all programming languages are Turing complete if the limitations of finite memory are ignored."

Comment: and some non programming languages are Turin complete. E.g. [minesweeper is Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#cite_note-10) - <del>mind</del> cell blown

Comment: Turing Complete is not a very high bar. Add a second stack to a pushdown automata and its Turing Complete. Add two counters to a NFA and it’s Turing Complete. I am not sure if folks know what this means. It is almost trivial to create a Turing Complete language.

Comment: @bolov A Turing machine has arbitrarily large, not infinite, memory. (Since a computation must terminate in a finite amount of time, it can only need a finite amount of memory.) I don't know where this idea of infinite memory comes from, but it's certainly not Turing.

Comment: @bolov • I presume "Turin complete" is a typo, because Turin complete programming languages are shrouded in mystery.

Comment: my friends if there's any language that's Turing complete, it's C++

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, from wikipedia [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)

> To show that something is Turing-complete, it is enough to show that
> it can be used to simulate some Turing-complete system. For example,
> an imperative language is Turing-complete if it has conditional
> branching (e.g., "if" and "goto" statements, or a "branch if zero"
> instruction; see one-instruction set computer) and the ability to
> change an arbitrary amount of memory (e.g., the ability to maintain an
> arbitrary number of data items).

Then [imperative languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Imperative_languages) lists C++ as such.

Comment: It should be noted that **technically** speaking, *C++ the language* is Turing complete, while any particular *implementation* (such as "`g++` on machine X") is not.

Comment: @bitmask Are you saying it can be made turing-complete by giving it infinite memory? C++ requires pointers to have finite size, so it might be impossible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not infinite, but arbitrarily large. So, although, **yes**, you cannot have an infinite amount of memory, you can at least have an arbitrary amount of it. So, it'd be conceivable to instantiate program X with 2^k bits of pointer-width until you run out of memory, then start again from scratch with 2^(k+1) bits, and so forth. Given that any program that **eventually halts** only uses a **finite amount** of memory for **that run**, you don't need infinite memory, you just need to be able to supply more memory indefinitely. In contrast, "g++ on X" has a fixed amount of memory.

Comment: ... however, the C++ standard *does* speak about *implementations*, so the abstract language cannot be fully decoupled from an actual implementation. Oh well, if we use the highly formal method of *squinting* C++ certainly *looks* Turing complete :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert of computational theory but as empirical law a language is declared Turing-complete if it supports  conditional branching, i.e. it must support if statements and go-to instruction. So the majority of languages out there is Turning-complete.

Ref. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

Comment: This is wrong: `goto`s are not **conditional** branches (conditional gotos exist in some languages, but are not the typical case) and a language that supports `if` statements as its sole control-flow statement is not turing-complete is it cannot emulate the simple `while (true) { }` program. Having `if` **and** `goto` is enough. Basically, you need some way to repeat previous statements and some way to decide behavior based on input.

Comment: In fact, just `while` is enough since `while` can easily simulate `if`.